# Deriving a well elaborated question on a delicate and difficult historical/actual topic

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've come across a thing/claim which is quite unpleasant but it comes from a blogger I have used to trust for a long time, he has also a considerable audience, and I've also double checked the historical reference of 1918 which at least seems to be quoted earlier but I do not know if it is truth indeed.

Please help me to draw on the quality of this question, if it is anyhow acceptable to this SE site. I'd like to work on the style to reduce the negative emotions to a possible extent to make the topic disputable.

---

Question title suggestion - "What does quoted Russian mass defecation mean in war/revolution context? Is this only Russia?"

That is, LG user [mi3ch](http://wikireality.ru/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2) claims that according to eyewitnesses he relates to, it has been observed that (possibly less well educated?) Russians are known to *mass defecate* (yes.. I apologize..) in contexts like war/revolution to express - hatred? dominance? I do not know but I would like to know the truth.

One reference is claimed to be 1918, Russian revolution.

Annenkow writes about his [house in Karelia](http://ristikivi.spb.ru/docs/kuokkala-annenkov-1.html). Note: Kuokkala is today's Repino.

"Непостижимо обильно испражнялись повсюду.." Юрий Анненков, дневники. "They defecated everywhere profusely, in an incomprehensible manner." [Yury Annenkov](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juri_Pawlowitsch_Annenkow) diaries.

The blogger I am referring to [claims also](https://mi3ch.livejournal.com/5337626.html) there were/are similar observations in Chechen war and also recently in the Ukrainian war.

The questions I ask myself:

- can this be truth?
- if yes - this can't be specific to Russians, there must be references from other countries as well?

Comment: Originally posted on [Main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377902/finding-context-for-a-question-about-sociology-history-collective-psychology?noredirect=1#comment1261319_377902) with a suggested redirect for skeptics.

Comment: We'd not be able to interpret it for you, at least not as the main question, but the claim seems sound as you've found the quote from the book.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the actual Live Journal article is being blocked from me with a [451 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_451).

There seems to be an extraordinary jump between the specific claims and the broader questions being asked here which makes me wonder about the notability.

The specific claims:

- Sometime in 1918, some members in a retreating army had literal pissing contests in a Finnish home, and left it covered in excrement.
- Sometime in 1919 (i.e. in the [middle of the October Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_Revolution)) some poor people expressed their disdain for the Romanovs at the Winter Palace by using expensive vases as chamber pots.
- Once, at an unnamed time and place, a cottage in Russia was robbed, and the thieves left a turd on a table.

I note that burglars defecating in inappropriate places in houses they are robbing is [not a rare occurrence](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1498102).

If you want to ask about those, sure.

But you aren't asking about that. You are asking about a far broader (and, I would argue, completely racist) claim that this is some reflection on all Russian people over the past 100 years (and Russian people specifically), that these incidences share a common intention of expressing dominance and hatred, and they are instances of "mass defecation" (without any clear definition of the term that would include these three examples).

It is tough to see how such a claim could be taken seriously. Alas, I can't see the claim or response to the claim to assess that. Perhaps you can find it on his [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/dmitry.chernyshev.5) account?

---

I neglected to address the higher-level question.

- We haven't yet identified any taboo subjects on Skeptics.SE.
- Our StackExchange masters originally asked us to avoid expletives. Sometimes we have let them through when the words themselves are the subject of the claim.
- We have marked links and images as "NSFW" to allow people to choose what they read.
- We have guidelines on discussing suicide.
- Due to Holocaust-denial trolls, questions on the subject tend to get tight scrutiny and short shrift, but they are not banned.

So, a question about defecation is not, in itself, a problem here.

Comment: I  look for other comparable references say to "poor people expressing disdain" exactly to clear away the "racist" perspective.

Comment: Why limit it to "poor people"? Does the question become "Is there any history of people expressing disdain by defecating in inappropriate places?" because Google is giving me hundreds of hits.

Comment: if you are talking about this, it's rather offtopic in this context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_defecation

Comment: No, I am talking about cases like those summarised in this article: https://www.bbc.com/news/world-44395861

Comment: "primal weapon" is good, right

Comment: More than just related: [What does Russian mass defecation mean? Is this only Russia? —closed— netvotes -3](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/68771/26786). Removed by post author, just like the mainMeta link ref'd in comments above.